# If $ f(\mathbb{D})=D$ where $D$ is star-shaped domain, show that $f(\mathbb{D}_r)$ is a star-shaped domain.

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$ which is injective with $f(\mathbb{D})=D$ and $f(0)=0$, where $D$ is a star-shaped domain. Show that $f(\mathbb{D}_r)$ is star-shaped domain where $\mathbb{D}_r=\{z:|z|<r\}, 0<r<1$.

I find it really difficult and I have no idea even on how to begin with this problem. I know that i want to show that for every point in $f(\mathbb{D}_r)$ the line segment with initial point at 0 and ending the chosen point is contained in $f(\mathbb{D}_r)$ but cannot use it properly.

Any hint or analytic solution would be very helpful as I want to understand the idea on how to solve this problem.

Comment: What has this got to do with convex analysis???

Comment: @copper.hat A convex set is star-shaped so maybe something can come from that. If it has no relation with convex analysis let me know so I can edit that.

Comment: $\mathbb{D}$ and $D$ are the same set, right? Also, I presume $\mathbb{D}_r = \{z:|z|<r\} \cap \mathbb{D}$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis No, $D$ is just a star-shaped region. $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit open disk centered at $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g=f^{-1}$ and fix $w \in f(\mathbb{D}_r), 0<t<1$ and let $g(w)=z$ so $|z|<r, f(z)=w$. Pick $0<t<1$ and we need to show that there is $|z_t|<r, f(z_t)=tw$

Let $|z|<|z_1|<r$ for some fixed $z_1$ and consider the function $h(u)=g(tf(uz/z_1))$ for $|u|<1$ (which is well defined since $D$, the domain of $g$, is starlike wr to $0$ so since $f(uz/z_1)$ is in it by definition, then $tf(uz/z_1)$ is in it too!)

Note that $h(0)=0, |h(u)|<1$ (since the image of $g$ is the unit disc) so by Schwarz Lemma we have $|h(u)| \le |u|$ and if we let $u=z_1$ we claim that $h(z_1)=z_t$ the required value in $\mathbb{D}_r$ since $|z_t|=|h(z_1)| \le |z_1|<r$, while $z_t=g(tf(z))=g(tw)$ hence $f(z_t)=tw$ so we are done!

The same kind of proof shows that if $f$ convex (univalent, $f(0)=0, f(\mathbb D)$ convex domain), then $f(\mathbb{D}_r)$ is also convex for all $0<r<1$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do we know that $g$ is holomorphic in $D$ so then we can apply the Schwarz Lemma?

Comment: The inverse of a holomorphic univalent function is holomorphic by the inverse function theorem which is basic stuff to be known before tackling geometric function theory

Comment: Pick any $z_0\in \partial D_r$.   Consider the  closed line segment from $w=0$ to $w= f(z_0)$. I believe that all you need is the Open Mapping Theorem  (and injectivity of $f$) to show that the image set $f(\overline D_r)$  is a relatively open and closed subset of this line segment.